# Filter two columns after Group By in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

I have two tables like the below query. I need to find out the setid from the table "data" which has all the records in the table "Searchlist" under one setid .

```
create table data(SetId int,drugid int, status varchar(1))
insert into data values (1,105,'A')
insert into data values (1,103,'I')

insert into data values (2,105,'A')
insert into data values (2,103,'A')

insert into data values (3,105,'A')

insert into data values (4,110,'A')

create table searchlist (id int, status varchar(1))
insert into searchlist values (105,'A')
insert into searchlist values (103,'I')
```

I have trying to do this but unable to match both the columns drugid and the status after doing group by SetId.

Kindly help.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Thanks. mysql tag is removed

Comment: Try to share a sample output for this. Not clear how do you want the data? By the way, share your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as relational division. One way is

```
select setid
from data d 
join searchlist s on d.drugid = s.id and (d.status=s.status or coalesce(s.status,'')='')
group by setid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from searchlist)
```

**EDITED**

Modified the query. `NULL` or `''` in `searchlist` matches any value.

Comment: I need setid from the table "data" which contains all the records in the searchlist

Comment: This is exactly what the query is doing. See more on relattional division at https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Comment: I am able to get the required data using your query. Can we pull the data if the status in the search list is null. Please guide

Comment: Please elaborate null case. Do you mean null matches null or any value?

Comment: Thanks. truncate table searchlist
insert into searchlist values (105,'A')
insert into searchlist values (103,'')

Comment: When the search table has records like the below, I need Set id which has 105 with A status and 103 with any status.                                                                    truncate table searchlist
insert into searchlist values (105,'A')
insert into searchlist values (103,'')

Comment: @SamuelFinny Change `d.status = s.status` to `(s.status = '' OR d.status = s.status)`

Comment: Thanks @Serg for your timely help